# Web.config Redirect HTTP to HTTPS, excluding sub-domains

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

This question has been asked before and I've browsed the suggestions questions before asking it myself.  Unfortunately I've not come across the answer I require.

I have rewrite in my Web.Config file for redirecting a TLD domain from HTTP to HTTPS.  The problem I have is that it redirects the sub-domain sites as well.  I only want the TLD to redirect and not the sub-domain sites.

For example I have www.example1.co.za  and www.example2.com

I require http://www.example2.com to redirect to https://www.example2.com, but not http://a.example2.com or any sub-domain of www.example2.com

It must also keep the redirect rule for http://example1.co.za to redirect to https://example1.co.za

Here is my Config code:

```
<rules>
    <clear />
    <rule name="Redirect to SSL for Mass" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example1\.co\.za$" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://example1.co.za" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="Redirect to SSL for Pro" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example2\.com$" />
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>                         
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://example2.com" />
    </rule>
</rules>
```

**EDIT**

I tried adding another rule to exclude sub-domains. however I get en error :(

```
<rule name="Exclude Sub Sites from Pro HTTPS Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"/>
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^*\.example2\.com$" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule will redirect:

`http://www.example.com` to redirect to `https://www.example.com`,

`http://example.com` to redirect to `https://example.com`

```
<rule name="Check SSL" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example\.com$" />
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    </conditions>                         
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This regexp `^(www\.)?example\.com$` is filtering requests, which have host different than `example.com` or `www.example.com`

Comment: will this exclude sub-domains?  so it will not redirect for sub.example.com?  just need to confirm before I test this on Live sites.

Comment: Yes, it will exclude all domain except: example.com or www.example.com

Comment: I have 2 rules for 2 Top Level domains. Will it also exclude that other domain?  Please see edited Question.

Comment: as per this code my other domain started load with http prefix any idea?

Comment: No, i do not have an idea, you can create a new question with your web.config rules and try to explain a problem and i will try to answer it